# Gradle task type:Exec cannot export env var

Tags: docker, gradle

Im trying to expose a service that is on my local to a docker network. In order to do so, i need to export the result of this command:

```
ip route show | grep docker0 | awk '{print \$9}'
```

Here is what my gradle task looks like

```
task exportEnvVariables( type:Exec ) {
    executable "sh"
    args "-c", "export", "HOST_IP=\$(ip route show | grep docker0 | awk '{print \$9}')"

    /* Have also tried:
    commandLine 'export HOST_IP=$(ip route show | grep docker0 | awk \'{print $9}\')' */

    println System.getenv( "HOST_IP" )
}
```

Comment: Did you manually check if your task works? Can you access the environment variable from the command line after you invoked Gradle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current approach cannot work, simply because you try to read the environment variable **before** you export it.

Whatever you put inside a task closure is executed during *configuration phase* (e.g. your `println` statement), while the actual task action is executed during *execution phase*.

You can use a `doLast` closure to execute a statement during *execution phase*:

```
task exportEnvVariables( type:Exec ) {
    executable "sh"
    args "-c", "export", "HOST_IP=\$(ip route show | grep docker0 | awk '{print \$9}')" 

    /* Have also tried: commandLine 'export HOST_IP=$(ip route show | grep docker0 | awk \'{print $9}\')' */

    doLast {
        println System.getenv( "HOST_IP" )
    }
}
```